# Cross-join like operation (with exceptions)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` of this form:

```
DT = data.table(i=1:3,a=10:12)
   i  a
1: 1 10
2: 2 11
3: 3 12
```

I would like this result:

```
   i j b
1: 1 2 21
2: 1 3 12
3: 2 1 21
1: 2 3 23
2: 3 1 22
3: 3 2 23
```

The idea is to do a cross-join on `i` with itself, excluding cases where `i == j`. And then `b=sum(a)`.

Comment: Are these values on 'b' correct.  Perhaps something like `CJ(i = DT$i, j = DT$i)[DT, b := a, on = .(i)][i!= j, b := sum(b), j][i != j]`

Comment: where does j come from?

Comment: how do you derive your result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it:

```
> DT[DT[CJ(i = i, j = i), on = 'i'], on = .(i = j)][i != i.i, .(i = i.i, j = i, a = a + i.a)]
   i j  a
1: 1 2 21
2: 1 3 22
3: 2 1 21
4: 2 3 23
5: 3 1 22
6: 3 2 23
```